# Create an aspell style file editing bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, lint

I'm creating a command line lint tool to run on Linux.

My output currently look like this:

```
./ex4/task6.7/SumOfCubedDigits.java
> Line 15 has inconsistent indenting
> Line 16 has inconsistent indenting
./ex2/task3.2/YearsBeforeRetirement.java
> Line 0 has a curly brace on the end
./ex2/task3.4/YearsBeforeRetirement.java
> Line 0 has a curly brace on the end
./ex2/task3.7/ThreeWeights.java
> Line 18 has inconsistent indenting
> Line 29 has inconsistent indenting
./ex2/task3.7/fourWeightsCoffeeTime/FourWeights.java
> Line 9 has inconsistent indenting
> Line 11 has inconsistent indenting
./ex2/task2.9/Limerick.java
> Line 0 has a curly brace on the end
```

By piping the output into `awk '/.\/ex/{print;}'` I can extract just the file names:

```
./ex4/task6.7/SumOfCubedDigits.java
./ex2/task3.2/YearsBeforeRetirement.java
./ex2/task3.4/YearsBeforeRetirement.java
./ex2/task3.7/ThreeWeights.java
./ex2/task3.7/fourWeightsCoffeeTime/FourWeights.java
./ex2/task2.9/Limerick.java
```

I would like to open each of these file in turn and edit them, maybe giving a message to the user with the errors in each file as I open them. Similar to what aspell does.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you execute the command from _within_ emacs?

Answer (score 1):

With [dialog](/questions/tagged/dialog) and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

Demo :

[image]

Code:

```
file=/path/to/file.txt

trap '\rm -f /tmp/out_file' 0 1 2 3 15

if dialog \
    --clear \
    --title "Pick up one of these files" \
    --menu "Files/errors" 80 300 100 $(
        awk '/>/{
            $1=""
            gsub(/ +/, "_", $0)
            arr[k]=arr[k] $0
            next
        }
        {k=$0}
        END{for (a in arr) printf "%s ", a " " arr[a]}
    ' "$file") 2>/tmp/out_file
then
    $EDITOR "$(</tmp/out_file)"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following `bash` script:

```
files=$(awk '/.\/ex/{print;}' input.txt)
for file in $files ; do
    echo "File: "$file
    echo "Errors:"
    awk -vfile=$file -f getErr.awk input.txt
    #open file in editor
done
```

where `input.txt` is the output from your `lint` command, and `getErr.awk` is

```
$0 ~ file {f=1; next}
f && /^> Line/ {print;next}
{f=0}
```